# Using ListTables when accessing File Geodatabase gives ArcPy IOError?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I am writing an arcpy script and testing against a file Geodatabase. I can open the Geodatabase workspace and iterate through the "ListFeatrueClasses".

However if I try to "ListFields" I get an IO Error.

I have already tried changing the workspace directory in various ways as suggested by other posts with no success. I also made sure the file Geodatabase is fully accessible and currently its on my local drive.

**This is the error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\Python-proj1\Python-proj1\openprimegeo.
>   py", line 29, in 
>       fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc1)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)  \ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy__init__.py", line  1138, in
>   ListFields
>       return gp.listFields(dataset, wild_card, field_type)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_bas e.py", line
>   346, in listFields
>       self._gp.ListFields(*gp_fixargs(args, True))) IOError: "Test_Polygon" does not exist
>
> C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5>

---

**Script:**

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/username/Downloads/prime/Prime_Template.gdb/Prime_Template.gdb"

print "starting..."

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in featureclasses:
    print fc

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcList
print "\n\n"
print "List Feature Class fields..."
print "\n\n"
for fc1 in fcList:
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc1)
    for field in fields:
        print "{0} is a type of {1} with a length of {2}".format(field.name, field.type, field.length)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments but it actually never gets that far. I have also actually commented out everything starting with "for field in fields:" and after to be sure. I posted it here without the comment tag so everyone can see everything

Comment: Yes, it does open in ArcMap and I am able to edit the data in the fields. But I will try the other suggestions as well.

Comment: I made a new geodatabase and copied the feature class and it worked. Thank you! -- I do not know how to mark this questoin as answered and supply you with the credit

Comment: Ah, glad we nailed it down! I've posted an answer you can accept, so we could close the thread!

Comment: Alex, I made a new geodatabase and copied the feature class and it worked. Thank you!...Now off to find out what was wrong with the submitted Geodatabase.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132139)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to read the feature classes using ArcMap connecting to this geodatabase, it may be corrupted.

If you are able, try creating a new file geodatabase and copy the feature classes into the newly created one.